# How to zip and unzip files on mac OS without losing creation date and time?

Tags: macos, zip

On a Mac, When I zip and unzip files using finder or using zip/ditto from command line, I lose the creation date of the files/folders and the creation date is automatically set same as the modification date. 
How can I preserve the creation date?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get file creation date.

   - (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
2. zip
3. set file creation date.

Answer (score 0):

Use tar with the p(reserve) option:

```
 tar -x -p -v -j -f arhive.tbz
```

Comment: Is tar on OSX different from GNU tar? For the latter the `p` option is `--preserve-permissions`.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tar.1.html

Comment: `-P` preserves absolute path names and has nothing to do with time information. `tar` always stores owner and permission information by default, and restores it again.

Comment: `-p` tries to preserves *permissions* (i.e. file mode, ACLs) *when restoring*. It's only applicable to `-x` (extraction). Plain old `tar cf` and `tar xf` preserve modification times already, no additional args needed. AFAIK creation date cannot be influenced.